# With Fidder Running all connections to ssl sites fail

Tags: ssl, fiddler

I have just recently installed fiddler, to watch calls made to my web API project from an office web App. These calls are sent over SSL so I enabled fiddler to decrypt HTTPS traffic. Installed the fiddler root certificate into my Firefox browser following these steps:
 http://www.telerik.com/blogs/configuring-firefox-for-fiddler

When connecting to any HTTPS site with fiddler running I receive this error.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 10:06:51.230
Connection: close

fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to mail.ionstaging.com (for #7) failed.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException Unspecified error
```